# why did it returned null after call miner.start()

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-design, golang, web3j

```
> miner.start()  
> null
```

> before it , I had created a account like this .

```
 user1 = eth.accounts[0] 
"0xb62f0bae52d153365661c4e23ab1d594484e9bef"
```

Comment: After you created an account, did you set the coinbase to that account? Miner needs an account to send earnings from the mining process.

Comment: This is -I think- normal. Check your console output to see if the mining has actually started.

Answer (score 11):

Recently, there are so many people confused about `miner.start(1)` returning null, but it's actually not a problem, just a reasonable return value misunderstanding. If you aren't sure that your node is mining, please execute `eth.hashrate` to check, if the return value is greater than zero, it is mining, otherwise, it is not.

Now let's analyze why `miner.start(1)` returns null. It might help to read the source code. When you execute the command `miner.start(1)` on the terminal, this would call `Start(threads *int)` method in [api.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/api.go#L140) source file, as follows:

```
// Start the miner with the given number of threads. If threads is nil the number
// of workers started is equal to the number of logical CPUs that are usable by
// this process. If mining is already running, this method adjust the number of
// threads allowed to use.
func (api *PrivateMinerAPI) Start(threads *int) error {
    // Set the number of threads if the seal engine supports it
    if threads == nil {
        threads = new(int)
    } else if *threads == 0 {
        *threads = -1 // Disable the miner from within
    }
    type threaded interface {
        SetThreads(threads int)
    }
    if th, ok := api.e.engine.(threaded); ok {
        log.Info("Updated mining threads", "threads", *threads)
        th.SetThreads(*threads)
    }
    // Start the miner and return
    if !api.e.IsMining() {
        // Propagate the initial price point to the transaction pool
        api.e.lock.RLock()
        price := api.e.gasPrice
        api.e.lock.RUnlock()

        api.e.txPool.SetGasPrice(price)
        return api.e.StartMining(true)
    }
    return nil
}
```

As the miner is not currently mining, `api.e.IsMining()` returns false, and then executes `api.e.StartMining(true)` function and returns its return value. Now let's read [its implementation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/backend.go#L324), as follows:

```
func (s *Ethereum) StartMining(local bool) error {
    eb, err := s.Etherbase()
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("Cannot start mining without etherbase", "err", err)
        return fmt.Errorf("etherbase missing: %v", err)
    }
    if clique, ok := s.engine.(*clique.Clique); ok {
        wallet, err := s.accountManager.Find(accounts.Account{Address: eb})
        if wallet == nil || err != nil {
            log.Error("Etherbase account unavailable locally", "err", err)
            return fmt.Errorf("singer missing: %v", err)
        }
        clique.Authorize(eb, wallet.SignHash)
    }
    if local {
        // If local (CPU) mining is started, we can disable the transaction rejection
        // mechanism introduced to speed sync times. CPU mining on mainnet is ludicrous
        // so noone will ever hit this path, whereas marking sync done on CPU mining
        // will ensure that private networks work in single miner mode too.
        atomic.StoreUint32(&s.protocolManager.acceptTxs, 1)
    }
    go s.miner.Start(eb)
    return nil
}
```

Please notice the return value of `StartMining(local bool)` method.It would return `nil` if the start mining process is successful, or return a detailed error message otherwise. So it's a frustrating return value, but it doesn't mean that the start mining process failed.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Loved the RTFS explanation for the null return code

Comment: Related question. Why is my hash rate 0 even though my block number 633?

Answer (score 6):

try setting `miner.setEtherbase(eth.coinbase)`

or step by step:

1. start Mist browser (let the node synchronize completely)
2. open console and type: `geth attach`
3. `miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])`
4. `miner.start()`

Even if it returns null you can see in the buttom left corner of Mist broser, that mining has startet. It takes a while till the hashrate incrases. You can check the current hashrate with `miner.getHashrate()`

Comment: Hi there. If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//ethereum.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: thanks for your help - Do you have an idea on how to solve the issue as well?

Comment: What does `eth.coinbase` show on your machine?

Comment: it shows my address 0x47Ba2C3c2880dcB31caA3DC644f4e895cB9d9bc4

Comment: have to say that I am running Mist and have started the console with:geth attach

Answer (score 3):

The `null` is expected. If you are mining you will see lots of messages in your console like this:

`INFO [07-25|18:46:25] Successfully sealed new block            number=72 hash=d0316e…36554e
INFO [07-25|18:46:25]  block reached canonical chain          number=67 hash=a89be4…5a73be
INFO [07-25|18:46:25]  mined potential block                  number=72 hash=d0316e…36554e
INFO [07-25|18:46:25] Commit new mining work                   number=73 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=158.932µs`

Try the following:

`eth.hashrate` will show you whether you are mining (make sure the number is a non-zero number).

If you are not mining, try explicitly starting the miner with one thread e.g. `miner.start(1)`

Though I wonder... are you mining on a private network / testnet?

Answer (score 1):

Some times the genesis.json with chainId:0 will create this issue, For me below genesis.json helped to solve the issue.

```
{
"config": {
"chainId": 45,
"homesteadBlock": 0,
"eip155Block": 0,
"eip158Block": 0
},
"alloc" : {},
"coinbase" : "0x75bcb134477f42f6fefbf177f9a610c0665e23a6",
"difficulty" : "0x20000",
"extraData" : "",
"gasLimit" : "0x2fefd8ffffffffff",
"nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
"mixhash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"timestamp" : "0x00"
}
```

Try with a fresh datadir, init this json, create account, configure with miner ( setEtherBase ), then start miner

miner.start(1) gave null for me. Also eth.hashrate is also 0. But mining works perfectly...!!!

Answer (score 1):

It sometimes so happens that the *geth you have attached shows NULL* but the other geth console will be showing up the mining trace.

Once you start mining check the other console for which the geth console is attached to, also wait for few minutes and then check for balance.

This happened in my case.