# How can I add some balance to the address in private blockchain testnet?

Tags: private-blockchain, balances

```
Geth
Version: 1.6.1-stable
Git Commit: 021c3c281629baf2eae967dc2f0a7532ddfdc1fb
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.8.1
Operating System: windows
GOPATH=
GOROOT=c:\go
```

The above is my geth installation, I need to initialize testnet with some default balance for some address - how can I do this? I tried with the genesis.json from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network and initialized the private block chain, created an account, replaced the address in the custom genesis file with that and re-run the init, but it failed with

```
Fatal: Failed to write genesis block: database already contains an incompatible genesis block (have 15ecff6ddb9d4db4, new 834a88447f2091cc)
```

How can I add some balance to the address?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the command:

```
miner.start()
```

In the geth console. This will start mining and add ether to your default account.

Comment: > miner.start()
null as that is what I get

Comment: [That is expected](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/why-did-it-returned-null-after-call-miner-start)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to set geth private net node on your machine, I posted the steps today in another question. This should help you out, please take a look.

[How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network/16306#16306)

Before following the steps, remove the existing datadir and genesis file.

Note - datadir folder has keystore and that has to be deleted to start from scratch

Once you set up private net then you can use `eth.SendTransaction({from: accounthash_sender, to: accounthash_reciever, value: the_amount})` to send some balance to other accounts from default account. Your default account would have balance from genesis block instantiation.