# miner.Start() Returns "null" - Its frustrating

Tags: ethminer, mac-osx

I set a private blockchain on Ethereum. Two nodes up and sync'ed as peers. Issue is it does not start mining.

miner.Start() Returns "null" - What can I do?

Have set eth.coinbase() return the a new account etc. So am not sure whats happening.

Comment: This has been asked before, though the current answer is downvoted: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/why-did-it-returned-null-after-call-miner-start

Comment: Please attempt the instructions on the answer to that question. If it works, upvote it, and delete your duplicate question. (If you don't delete it, it'll get flagged as duplicate anyway.)

Comment: There was no accepted anwer to that post, only one suggested answer that got no upvotes, so why would he trust it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try `miner.start(1)` from the geth console, the number in parenthesis is the number of threads. To stop type `miner.stop()`