# How to restart mining in my private blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

[image][image]I successfully setup a private blockchain in my laptop and mined around 5160 Ether (no market value). Also deployed a smart contract.

Now I had to close my laptop and when I came back and turned the system on, with all the steps, my wallet on my private block chain is showing 5160 Ethers, but I am not able to mine further and the hash rate is 0.0 KH/s even after miner.start(1); command in geth for around 20 minutes. Where am I going wrong and how to resume mining on my private blockchain? In the first attempt the hash rate was quite decent.

Comment: This seems to be similar to https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23772/why-does-miner-start-return-null-does-not-start-in-private-testchain?noredirect=1#comment25603_23772  (miner.start() takes a LONG time to start). Can you try `debug.verbosity(4);miner.start(1);admin.sleepBlocks(3);miner‌​.stop();debug.verbos‌​ity(3);` to help understand what is the matter. Also - do you have just one node running or more than one?

Comment: @AlanBuxton Thanks for the debugging steps. I have used them and can see the Ethereum handshake failed due to genesis block mismatch. But the genesis.json is intact and have not been changed.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the right ```--datadir dirname``` param when starting your geth node this time round? If you are using different directory name (or none at all) then you could be accidentally using a directory that uses a different ```genesis.json```. The ```genesis.json``` is only used when initialising the node - it's not relevant at startup time.

Comment: @AlanBuxton a peculiar thing happened. Just after posting my comment, the damn thing started to mine. Later I stopped it myself. Again while restarting it after several hours, it was not starting and is being like that ever since. I wonder what the RCA might be, is that something to do with the cache memory? OR the initial DAG formation is a hit-and-trial affair? Just random guess. Not sure though. Would be great if you could share some pointers/link to proceed with further investigation.