# geth miner.start() returns null

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, hashrate

I've read answers to several similar questions, but they seem not to be on point.

I have geth 1.10.8 installed on Windows 10. I created private network, and the coinbase is set correctly. When I pass a command miner.start() it returns null. If I check eth.hashrate it returns 0. However, if the first command I pass is miner.stop() follwed by miner.start(), it returns some lines of information but no mining is taking place. Hashrate is still 0. Here are the commands and the message geth returns:

```
> miner.stop()
null
> miner.start()
INFO [08-29|12:48:50.059] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=1
nuIlNlFO
[08-> 29|12:48:50.065] Commit new mining work                   number=8 sealhash=b6914a..9a7d20 uncles=0 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed=0s
INFO [08-29|12:48:50.065] Sealing paused, waiting for transactions
> eth.hashrate
0
>
```

I had previously geth version 1.7.0 installed and mining worked as expected with no such weird behavior.

How do I make it mine?

Comment: It is not important, it is the way the console works it has to print the result from last statement. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23772/why-does-miner-start-return-null-does-not-start-in-private-testchain

Comment: So how do I make it mine?

Comment: Add details like which command did you use, how is your genesis file looks like?

Comment: @Merger It should have started mining if it is synchronized. Is it a PoA or PoW private network?